# MySql Syntax Error (using joins)

Tags: c#, mysql, mysql-error-1064

I can't find the error in MYSQL Syntax:

```
"SELECT customer.CustomerCode, customer.CustomerName, customer.CustomerAddress, customer.CustomerHandphone, customer,CustomerEmail, product.ProductCode, product.ProductName, product.ProductPrice, orderdetail.OrderCode, orderdetail.ProductCode, orderdetail.ProductPrice, orderlist.OrderCode, orderlist.CustomerCode, orderlist.OrderPrice " +
                     "FROM customer INNER JOIN (product INNER JOIN (orderlist INNER JOIN(orderdetail INNER JOIN ON orderlist.OrderCode = orderdetail.OrderCode) ON product.ProductCode = orderdetail.ProductCode) ON customer.CustomerCode = orderlist.CustomerCode) " +
                     "Where orderlist.OrderCode =@orderdetail.OrderCode " +
                        "GROUP BY customer.CustomerCode, customer.CustomerName, customer.CustomerAddress, customer.CustomerHandphone, customer,CustomerEmail, product.ProductCode, product.ProductName, product.ProductPrice, orderdetail.OrderCode, orderdetail.ProductCode, orderdetail.ProductPrice, orderlist.OrderCode, orderlist.CustomerCode, orderlist.OrderPrice";"
```

Error is below
1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON orderlist.OrderCode = orderdetail.OrderCode) ON product.ProductCode = orderde' at line 1

Comment: `INNER JOIN (orderlist INNER JOIN (orderdetail` etc. is invalid syntax, just as the error says. The proper syntax is `INNER JOIN <tableB> ON <TableB.column> = <TableA.column> INNER JOIN <tableC> ON <tableC.column> = <TableB.column>`. Find a SQL tutorial or book (or read the MySQL documentation, just as the error message tells you to do).

Answer (score 1):

Write the query with an `ON` clause following each `JOIN`.  This is just so much easier to read and write and is probably your problem:

```
SELECT c.CustomerCode, c.CustomerName, c.CustomerAddress, c.CustomerHandphone, c.CustomerEmail,
       p.ProductCode, p.ProductName, p.ProductPrice,
       od.OrderCode, od.ProductCode, od.ProductPrice, od.OrderCode,
       ol.CustomerCode, ol.OrderPrice " +
FROM orderlist ol INNER JOIN
     orderdetail od
     ON ol.orderCode = od.OrderCode INNER JOIN
     customer c 
     ON c.CustomerCode = ol.CustomerCode INNER JOIN
     product p
     ON p.ProductCode = od.ProductCode;
```

In addition, the `ORDER BY` seems unnecessary.  Typically it would be used with aggregation functions.  If you are getting duplicates somehow (which seems unlikely) use `SELECT DISTINCT`.

Finally, I don't understand this:

```
Where ol.OrderCode = @orderdetail.OrderCode
```

I don't think `@orderdetail.OrderCode` is valid syntax.  If you want to pass in a variable, it would look more like:

```
Where ol.OrderCode = @OrderCode
```